# How to check deque length in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-structures

How to check a deque's length in python?

I don't see they provide deque.length in Python...

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
from collections import deque
queue = deque(["Eric", "John", "Michael"])
```

How to check the length of this deque?

and can we initialize like

```
queue = deque([])   #is this length 0 deque?
```

Comment: Did you try `len(queue)`? That's usually how Python handles element counts.

Comment: `print(len(my_queue.queue))` worked for me.

Comment: I hesitate to edit a question with this many upvotes, but I think there is a case for using a word other than "queue" in the question title and body, since many google searches about python `Queue` are going to end up here, and the accepted answer simply will not work for a `Queue`. (and yes, I know a `deque` is also a type of queue - it's just an unfortunate word in this case...)

Comment: For computing the length of a `queue.Queue` (or `multiprocessing.Queue`) object, refer to [Get length of Queue in Python's multiprocessing library - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952413/get-length-of-queue-in-pythons-multiprocessing-library)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`len(queue)` should give you the result, 3 in this case.

Specifically, `len(object)` function will call `object.__len__` method [[reference link](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)]. And the object in this case is `deque`, which implements `__len__` method (you can see it by `dir(deque)`).

---

```
queue= deque([])   #is this length 0 queue?
```

Yes it will be 0 for empty `deque`.

Comment: AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute '__len__' I used qsize() instead https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html

Comment: @memo: read the question body. `collections.deque` is different from `queue.Queue`. The latter is expected to be used in a multithreading case where the size may be changed in another thread.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no such attribute at all.

Comment: @SmallChess Are you sure? It definitely does exist for a `collections.deque` which is what the question is asking. Per the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects towards the end of the section... *"In addition to the above, deques support iteration, pickling, **len(d),**..."* (emphasis mine).

Comment: @SmallChess, make sure it's queue= deque([])  rather than queue= deque()

Answer (score 64):

it is simple just use .qsize()
example:

```
a=Queue()
a.put("abcdef")
print a.qsize() #prints 1 which is the size of queue
```

The above snippet applies for `Queue()` class of python. Thanks [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) for the update.

for `deque from collections` we can use `len()` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548492/6663095) by [K Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853611/k-z).

Comment: Please note that this is for the `Queue` class, which is not the same as the one from `collections.deque`, which is what the OP is actually asking for.

Comment: @rayryeng But it brought googlers like me to the answer they _did_ expect!  Not sure why the `queue.Queue` class has no regular length…

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can check the length of queue object created from collections.

```
from collections import deque
class Queue():
    def __init__(self,batchSize=32):
        #self.batchSie = batchSize
        self._queue = deque(maxlen=batchSize)

    def enqueue(self, items):
        ''' Appending the items to the queue'''
        self._queue.append(items)

    def dequeue(self):
        '''remoe the items from the top if the queue becomes full '''
        return self._queue.popleft()
```

Creating an object of class

```
q = Queue(batchSize=64)
q.enqueue([1,2])
q.enqueue([2,3])
q.enqueue([1,4])
q.enqueue([1,22])
```

Now retrieving the length of the queue

```
#check the len of queue
print(len(q._queue)) 
#you can print the content of the queue
print(q._queue)
#Can check the content of the queue
print(q.dequeue())
#Check the length of retrieved item 
print(len(q.dequeue()))
```

check the results in attached screen shot

[image]

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you run into a problem where the error is

> "AttributeError: collections.deque has no attribute length"

Then the reason is that you probably used JavaScript syntax in Python, i.e. you tried to call

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.append(2)
q.length # This is wrong
```

The correct way to get the length of a deque is just the Pythonic `len()` function

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q.append(2)
print(len(q))
```