# Get length of Queue in Python's multiprocessing library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.Manager` object that contains a `multiprocessing.Queue` to manage all of the work that I want a group of processes to do. I would like to get the number of elements left in this queue and was wondering how to do this?

Python's inbuilt `len()` function does not work.

Comment: Related question: [python queue get size, use qsize() or len()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647274/python-queue-get-size-use-qsize-or-len)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the queue you are talking about is `multiprocessing.Queue`, try to use [**`qsize()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize) method for `multiprocessing.Queue` objects, but be careful:

> qsize()
>
> Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of
>   multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable.
>
> Note that this may raise NotImplementedError on Unix platforms like
>   Mac OS X where sem_getvalue() is not implemented.

Comment: What is the solution to NotImplementedError

Comment: One way to work around `NotImplementedError` is to define your custom Queue class that allows `.qsize()` method. Here is one working example in Python3: https://gist.github.com/FanchenBao/d8577599c46eab1238a81857bb7277c9